# How to configure Firestore without using .json file in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Spring boot 2.7 and firebase-admin 7.1.0 dependency. I need to create a Firestore bean using Firestore credentials. I didn't find any way to set credentials using `application.properties` or by setting the environment variables. The only way I found was to get credentials using a `.json` file. I feel this is not **secure**.

```
@Value("${firebase.credential.path}")
private String credentialPath;

@Bean
public Firestore getFireStore() throws IOException {
    FileInputStream serviceAccount = null;
    try {
        serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(credentialPath);
        var credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount);

        var options = FirestoreOptions.newBuilder()
                .setCredentials(credentials).build();

        return options.getService();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Error in firebase authentication bean: {}", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to set credentials in the `application.properties` file or use environment variables if not Is it secure to take credentials from a separate `.json` file?

Comment: I am trying to do the same with a .NET Api, if you get an answer it would be very helpfull

Answer (score 1):

I dont no if thats a good way to solve this, but its working for me:

```kotlin
    @Bean
    fun provideFirebaseOptions(): FirebaseApp {
        val jsonObject = JsonObject()
        jsonObject.addProperty("type", type)
        jsonObject.addProperty("project_id", projectId)
        jsonObject.addProperty("private_key_id", privateKeyId)
        // to get linebreaks inside env variable
        jsonObject.addProperty("private_key", privateKey.replace("\\n", "\n"))
        jsonObject.addProperty("client_email", clientEmail)
        jsonObject.addProperty("client_id", clientId)
        jsonObject.addProperty("auth_uri", authUri)
        jsonObject.addProperty("token_uri", tokenUri)
        jsonObject.addProperty("auth_provider_x509_cert_url", authProviderX509CertUrl)
        jsonObject.addProperty("client_x509_cert_url", clientX509CertUrl)
        
        val inputStream = ByteArrayInputStream(jsonObject.toString().toByteArray())
        val options = FirebaseOptions.builder()
            .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(inputStream))
            .build()
        return FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options)
    }
```

Maybe you dont need `.replace("\\n", "\n"))` for the private key. I had some problems with linebreaks inside environment variables.